# Passing a php variable to another php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have some `div`s with class `content-full` which are created according to the data stored in a *MySQL* table. For example, if I have 3 rows there will be 3 `div`s.

When I click on any of the `div`s then the data associated with the *ID* for that `div` should be displayed inside `div` `content-full`. However, the content associated with the last `div` appears when I click on any of the `divs` because I am not passing any kind of variable *ID* that can be used to specify the clicked `div`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".content-short").click(function() {                //

      $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",
        url: "content.php",               //
        dataType: "text",                  
        success: function(response){                    
            $(".content-full").html(response); 
        }

      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

***content.php***

```
 <?php
     include "mysql.php";
     $query= "SELECT Content FROM blog limit 1";
     $result=mysql_query($query,$db);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
           echo $row['Content'];          
       }
     mysql_close($db);  

    ?>
```

Is there an alternate way to do this or something that I need to correct for it to work?

Thanks

Comment: I'de like to mention that `mysql_` is deprecated and you should switch to something much safer like PDO. For the rest you will have to probably use `POST` instead of `GET` and pass it data like `id=2` and then run your query as such.

Comment: i don't have any idea about ajax so please correct the code @somethinghere

Comment: You _cannot_ get a different result back since your query is always the same. If you ask me `how tall are you?` every time, you will get the same answer everytime! Now if you could ask me `How tall is Person X?` and then change that `Person` every time, then you're getting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you will have to pass actual data to the your PHP script. Let's first deal with the JavaScript end. I am going to *assume* that your HTML code is printed using php and you are able to create something like the following: `<div class=".content-short" data-id="2" />`:

```
$(".content-short").click(function() {
  // get the ID
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({   
        type: "post",
        url: "content.php",
        data: 'id=' + id
        dataType: "text",                  
        success: function(response){                    
            $(".content-full").html(response); 
        }
    });
});
```

Next up is *reading* the value you passed in using the script:

```
<?php
include "mysql.php";
// Use the $_POST variable to get all your passed variables.
$id     = isset($_POST["id"]) ? $_POST["id"] : 0;
// I am using intval to force the value to a number to prevent injection.
// You should **really** consider using PDO.
$id     = intval($id);
$query  = "SELECT Content FROM blog WHERE id = " . $id . " limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Content'];          
}
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

There you go, I have modified your query to allow fetching by id. There are two **major** caveats:

First: **You should not use the `mysql_` functions anymore and they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP soon if it has not happened yet!**, secondly: I cannot guarantee that the query works, of course, I have no idea what you database structure is.

The last problem is: what to do when the result is empty? Well, usually AJAX calls send and respond with JSON objects, so maybe its best to do that, replace this line:

```
 echo $row['Content'];
```

with this:

```
 echo json_encode(array('success' => $row['Content']));
```

Now, in your `success` function in JS, you should try to check if there a success message. First of, change `dataType` to `json` or remove that line entirely. Now replace this success function:

```
success: function(response){                    
    $(".content-full").html(response); 
}
```

into this:

```
success: function(response){
    if(response.success) $(".content-full").html(response);
    else alert('No results');
}
```

Here the deprecation 'notice' for the mysql_ functions: http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php

Comment: i will  definitely  give it a try and also i don't have this //data-id="2"//. i initially has data in content-short which is also from same database so any  other way other then using //data-id="2"// @somethinghere

Comment: You will need some way of identifying and matching data. Like i mentioned in the comment, without it you wre just asking a grneric question over and over. Good luck.

Comment: i did this is this anyhow logical 
echo "<div class='content-short' data-id=".$row['ID'].">";

Comment: Yes it is. Dont forget do make sure your capitalisation of `id` is the same everywhere.

Comment: but it isn't working as i excatly copied the code you gave

Comment: I cannot know your db structure,mate. Make sure the id prints coreectly. I also removed the document ready. Match all capitalisations correctly. Debug. Cannot help much more! Good luck.

Comment: Could you mark this as the correct answer then? Cheers!

Comment: sir but now whnever i click on any div it changes the content but it then populates every content-full div with the same data instead of that particulat associated content full, so any help on this
its not a issue but still any help
and i already marked but that reputation problem.

Comment: Then each of them has the same id. You will have to loop through the rows in your db and use the row id to get different results. Sorry but this is becoming guesswork at this point :) also, you dont need rep to mark an answer to your own question :)

Comment: sir a little bit more help now i am passing two variables 
var collegename = $(this).attr('value');
data: {'ID=' + ID + 'collegename=' + collegename},

and in content.php

$collegename     = isset($_POST["collegename"]) ? $_POST["collegename"] : 0;

but it isn't working i m not getting anything sir please help

Comment: You have to string together variables with an `&` sign or use jqueries `serialize()` on your form. So `'id='+id+'&collegename='+collegename`

Comment: it is also not working is there anything wrong in content.php file 
$collegename = isset($_POST["collegename"]) ? $_POST["collegename"] : 0; @somethinghere

Comment: I honestly cannot say. Is your form using `post`? Have a read at this as it explains the basics very well: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp - also, try using `print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET` to see what arrays are passed to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at passing a parameter to your script, generally like an id by which you can search in the db.

The easiest way to achieve this is by get parameters on the url 
    `url: "content.php?param=2",`

Then in php:
`<?php $param = $_GET['param']; 
...`

Comment: i don't have any idea about ajax so please correct the code @think